# C# Copy file or folder

Tags: c#, file, copy, directory

I am trying to write a program to keep multiple folders in sync.  To do this, I need to copy and delete files and subfolders.

To me, it doesn't make a difference if an object is a file or a folder, I want to create all necessary parent folders and copy the object, overwriting if necessary.  I'm currently using a jagged array of FileSystemInfo to hold my files/folders.

This has the advantage of avoiding a duplication of code to sync files and folders separately.

However, I can't figure out how to Copy a FileSystemInfo.  I'm looking for a way to be able to copy/delete/read creation or modified time that will work on both files and folders.

Comment: There is no .NET or Windows API function that will copy a file if given a file name, or a folder if given a folder name. Nor should there be. Files and folders are fundamentally different things. If you want to treat them the same in your code, then you have to write the logic that figures out which is which, and makes the appropriate system calls.

Comment: Why are reproducing robocopy? Something along the lines of `Process.Start("robocopy", root + " /MIR")` seems like your best bet.

Comment: Jim - I was afraid that might be the case.  I know that they are different, but in this case, I want to treat them similarly, since I want someone to be able to create or delete a folder and have that synced, regardless of if it contains files.

Comment: whoisj - I've never heard of robocopy.  What is it?  Also, as a side note, does anyone know how to create a line-break in your comment?

Comment: Robocopy is a command line tool that comes with Windows. Do `Robocopy /?` at the command line, or use your favorite search engine. And you can't put a line break in your comment. Edit your question if your comment is that detailed.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I was just trying to reply to two different people.  Is accepted practice to double-post, or to anwer multiple people in one comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used sam's answer to help me solve my problem.  What I did was put the copying logic in my custom class so that I don't need to duplicate the logic whenever I use it in my code.

```
public class myFSInfo
{
    public FileSystemInfo Dir;
    public string RelativePath;
    public string BaseDirectory;
    public myFSInfo(FileSystemInfo dir, string basedir)
    {
        Dir = dir;
        BaseDirectory = basedir;
        RelativePath = Dir.FullName.Substring(basedir.Length + (basedir.Last() == '\\' ? 1 : 2));
    }
    private myFSInfo() { }
    /// <summary>
    /// Copies a FileInfo or DirectoryInfo object to the specified path, creating folders and overwriting if necessary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    public void CopyTo(string path)
    {
        if (Dir is FileInfo)
        {
            var f = (FileInfo)Dir;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path.Substring(0,path.LastIndexOf("\\")));
            f.CopyTo(path,true);
        }
        else if (Dir is DirectoryInfo) Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FileSystemInfo don't have Copy or Delete methods but is the base class for DirectoryInfo and FileInfo.

So when you loop over your FileSystemInfo objects you have to cast to the proper concrete class and use the specific copy/delete methods.

```
foreach( var fsi in fileSystemInfoObjects )
{
     if( fsi is DirectoryInfo )
     {
        var directory =  (DirectoryInfo)fsi;
        //do something
     }
     else if (fsi is FileInfo )
     {
        var file = (FileInfo)fsi;
        //do something
     }
}
```

Comment: I can add casting logic, but is there a way to have only one "do something" section?  If not, then this is just putting the IF statement inside the loop, which doesn't do much over copying my entire syncing loop and doing it separately for files and folders.  If I have to do it separately, I can, but it would be cleaner if there is a way to perform the same actions on files and folders, even if I need to do some casting.

Comment: It depend on what you have to do cause a method could have a different signature in DirectoryInfo and FileInfo classes. I'd take a different approach in your case: since FileInfo's Copy method creates all subdrirectories i would work only with  files. Enumerate from a root directory and just copy.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use the FileInfo Copy method to create subdirectories?  I've been having to use Directory.CreateDirectory to make the folder and then FileInfo.Copyto to copy.